# Center an image in header, also make full-width

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for hours to get a logo centered and full-width across the top of my global header. CANNOT seem to figure it out. I'm working in a cart software program, and may not be editing the right things...

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container">
    <header id="header"> 
        <div id="logo">
            <!--START: global_header-->
            <h1 class="store-name">[storename]</h1>
            <h3 class="store-slogan">[storeslogan]</h3>
            <!--END: global_header-->
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#logo img {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] and the actual image it's hard to help.

Comment: I don't see any img element inside your logo div. Are you sure it is not a background image instead ?

Comment: I should add, this is what it keeps doing, and I'd like that logo image (it's a placeholder at this point) to go across the entire container http://tinypic.com/r/10eg1fc/9

Comment: Would you have a plunkr to look at all? Just so I have an idea of what you're trying to achieve then I can maybe help you :)

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi See, I'm not a smart woman. I input my image into the cart software and it pulls it to the template, but I don't like the way it's resized and am trying to figure out how to make it do what I want. :-/

Comment: WHy are you using max-width? It should be "width:100%"

Comment: @RachelS replacing max-width with width didn't change anything. Is there something in the background that I'm maybe not seeing? I'm not a dev, I'm in marketing, trying to stumble through this...

Comment: If that is the exact code from the page then it might be a background image and you can center it by adding: `background-position: center;` to your div.

Comment: Ok, so another way I can do it is by putting the logo into the header section of the cart software, with this HTML:

    <div align="center"><img alt="" src="/assets/images/NewGlarus(1).png" border="0px"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I created an example on Plunker. Using the ID you set for your header div you can add a background image URL as well and the position of the background. Not sure where you wanted the text.

```
#header {
  text-align: center;
   background-image: url('http://placehold.it/360x65');
   background-position: center; 
}


https://plnkr.co/edit/7Gpf8kePPXQ4MfoSXVKh?p=preview
```